# Pentaho Kettle refreshing mondrian cache

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a step in my transformation to refresh Mondrian Schema Cache.

This is achieved by calling the following rest end point:

```
${PentahoBaseUrl}/api/system/refresh/mondrianSchemaCache
```

I have this call as a `HTTP client` step.

```
https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/HTTP%20Client
```

`HTTP Client` step can take `Proxy` information as `Proxy Host` and `Proxy Port`. I have introduced the following properties in `kettle.properties` file: `HTTP.Proxy.Host` and `HTTP.Proxy.Port`. And am setting them up in the step as:

[image]

Now, when my `kettle.properties` have these entries with values, the step runs fine. However, we may have instances where proxy is not required and thus the entries will be missing from `kettle.properties`. The behaviour I am expecting from the step is to ignore the entries if they are missing.

However, the step fails complaining that the properties could not be resolved.

How can I set this up in the way I want?

Comment: Which version of PDI you are using to setup this process? As I am trying to reproduce your error. Every time I found its working if there have no proxy entry in kettle.properties but used in the 'Proxy to use' section.

Comment: I am using 9.1 version of PDI..

Comment: I did not found any error if proxy variable not available in 'Kettle.properties' file..Also I am using Pentaho BA server 8.1 CE and PDI 9.1 CE .Can you please share your transformation?

Comment: when you required proxy parameter pass it otherwise skip it, this can be achieved through logic, modify your process accordingly.

Comment: @HelpingHand.. Can you please point me to an approach ? as in how can I pass proxy variables to HTTP Client step conditionally ?